# Trailing slash in url and virtual host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, laravel, virtualhost

I have a laravel project on localserver and want it to work even when the trailing slash is added to the url. It is working fine when accessed with localhost url. The htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /LaravelProject/public/


# Redirect Trailing Slashes...

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Trying to access page like

```
http://localhost/LaravelProject/public/login 
and 
http://localhost/LaravelProject/public/login/
```

is working fine.

However I have also VirtualHost defined like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/LaravelProject/public"
    ServerName LaravelProject.dev
    ServerAlias www.LaravelProject.dev
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Via url `laravelproject.dev`, I can access the document root and can see the "You have arrived." But when I try to access other url say `laravelproject.dev/login`, it gives me `500 Internal Server Error`.

If I remove the `RewriteBase` from `.htaccess` and modify the `RewriteRule` as

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

then the urls `laravelproject.dev/login` and `laravelproject.dev/login/` work fine.
If I do this, again the problem persists with `localhost` url with trailing slashes and the
url `http://localhost/LaravelProject/public/login/` redirects to `http://localhost/login`.

I want to be able to use both **localhost** and **virtualhost** urls **with and without** trailing slashes and give the same result. As it seems, it is one or the other for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any of these lines in your .htaccess file. I have got mine set up like this on a couple of projects and it works perfectly fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Following your approach, when I add the trailing slash to the url, that page works. But when I navigate to other links from that page, the url just gets appended as the RewriteBase is not set. That is just for the localhost url. Even if I set the RewriteBase it does not work for the non localhost url like laravelproject.dev.

Comment: This leads me to the conclusion that the big problem comes from your virtual host. Try replacing *:80 with the concrete virtual name laravelproject.dev:80. It should look like this http://pastebin.com/agT8HrRC